# Incomplete display of style in geoserver generated in QGIS

Tags: geoserver, qgis, wms, sld

SLD generated in QGIS 2.10 PISA is as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>state1</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>state1</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ADJACENT COUNTRIES</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d640d1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#62eadf</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ANDHRA PRADESH</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ANDHRA PRADESH</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ANDHRA PRADESH</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#869edf</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ARUNACHAL PRADESH</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ARUNACHAL PRADESH</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ARUNACHAL PRADESH</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#85e6ee</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>ASSAM</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>ASSAM</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ASSAM</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#aede72</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
  <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>STATE is ''</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ebcf60</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The above SLD when added as a style to one of the layers in GeoServer 2.7.2 and published as a wms, is not able to display the labels(state names). In SLD, only the states are categorized and names have been given to them.
Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLD does not contain any TextSymbolizer, so there is no way it can display labels. If you have labels configured, you should report the lack of a TextSymbolizer as a bug in QGis

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since the labels have been configured, it seems to be a bug in qgis because the above sld has been generated in QGIS.